# Does Session object in request pakage support status code?

Tags: python, python-requests

If I do `r = requests.get()` then I can access the status code by `r.status_code`.

But when I am using `s = requests.Session()`, I cannot access status code

May be I am missing something. Please help in that case.

Comment: Put the code back. It shows exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With sessions you make a request with `r = s.get(url)`, then you access it the same way with `r.status_code`.

```py
import requests

s = requests.Session()
r = s.get("https://example.com")
print(r.status_code)
```